# Updating pre-existing things already in a database mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently using mongodb in a express application via mongoose and a random thought came upon me. What would happen if say you had a site with users and later on you made a update and needed to add a new field to all the user models. how would you go about updating all pre-existing users with the new field.

Comment: You need to run some update query manually(Migration)

Answer (score 0):

You would use `updateMany` in your mongo shell (or using driver - the same):

```
db.user.updateMany({}, { $set: { newField: value } });
```